# React - Element Type is Invalid Error on Form.File onChange Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm developing a user registration feature in a React app, where I'm using the react-bootstrap library for form inputs and the Cloudinary service for image uploads.

I have a RegisterScreen component where users can enter their information and upload a profile picture. The picture is then uploaded to Cloudinary using their API.

The issue arises when I try to render the RegisterScreen component. The error message is:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of RegisterScreen.
```

However, when I remove the part of my code related to the image upload, everything works fine, and the component renders without any error. It seems the issue is specifically tied to the image upload feature.

Any kind of help would work.

Here is the problematic piece of code:

```js
const postDetails = (pics) => {
  if (!pics) {
    return setPicMessage("Please enter a picture");
  }
  setPicMessage(null);
  if (pics.type === "image/jpeg" || pics.type === "image/png") {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", pics);
    data.append("upload_preset", "myCS_IA");
    data.append("cloud_name", "dxghfraof");
    fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dxghfraof", {
      method: "post",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
          setPic(data.url.toString());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  } else {
    return setPicMessage("Please enter a picture");
  }
};

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  postDetails(file);
};

<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPic">
  <Form.Label>Profile Picture Upload</Form.Label>
  <Form.File
    id="custom-file"
    type="file"
    label="Upload your Profile Image"
    onChange={handleFileChange}
  />
</Form.Group>
```